# How to list files whose names are a substring of files to ignore

Tags: bash, unix

Hello I'm new with bash and I'd like to know in which way I can list files that can end by one or two digits.

e.g.

```
hello1
hello2
hello3
hello11
```

are the files i want to list in a directory, but that directory also includes files I don't want to list such as:

```
hello2-super
hello3_nice
hello1-the_best1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
ls *[0-9]
```

to list all the files that end in a digit, or replace the [0-9] with other groups if you have different matches in the future you want.

If you want to get all the "hello{digits}" type files but exclude "hello1-the_best1" you can use extended globs in bash, or you could use grep.  With extended globs:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls hello[0-9]?([0-9])
```

which will enable extended globs, then match hello followed by 1 or 2 digits

with grep you could do

```
ls | egrep "^hello[0-9]{1,2}$"
```

which will do the same, but requires a subshell and second process

Comment: Another option would be ls | egrep [0-9]+$

Comment: my problem is with files like hello1-the_best1 that i don't want in the output  of ls

Comment: @steT so is there a pattern that you can use to distinguish between "good" and "bad" files since apparently ending in a digit isn't what you want.  I can't really tell from your examples what you do and don't want to match

Comment: i want to get all the hello(digit) with ls keeping out for example hello1-the_best1

Comment: @steT I've updated my answer to hopefully help with that situation